# Por que no veo nuevos archivos en mi servidor MiniDLNA?

Tags: servidor

Desde hace tiempo tengo muchos problemas con el servidor multimedia "minidlna" para armbian en orange pi zero... No se ven los nuevos archivos... A veces no aparece el servidor en la smart TV... (Aun estando "active"). Tengo todo configurado y no tengo ni idea de que puede ir mal, estoy eliminando el files.db, haciendo sudo minidlnad -R (aparece en la smart tv, pero con archivos antiguos), no funciona (para que aparezca el servidor en mi linia) el hacer start, restart, force-reload, stop && start en el servicio de minidlna....

Sinceramente no se de donde viene el problema, como puedo arreglarlo? Tengo puesto iniciar como mi usuario.

LOG

[2017/12/01 11:18:51] playlist.c:125: warn: Parsing playlists...
[2017/12/01 11:18:51] playlist.c:259: warn: Finished parsing playlists.
[2017/12/01 11:18:52] sql.c:117: warn: sql_get_int_field: step failed: SQL logic error or missing database
SELECT (select count(distinct DETAIL_ID) from OBJECTS o left join DETAILS d on (o.DETAIL_ID = d.ID) where (OBJECT_ID glob '*$*') and (o.CLASS like "item.audioItem%" and REF_ID is NULL)) + (select count(*) from OBJECTS o left join DETAILS d on (o.DETAIL_ID = d.ID) where (OBJECT_ID = '*') and (o.CLASS like "item.audioItem%" and REF_ID is NULL))
[2017/12/01 11:18:52] upnpsoap.c:123: warn: Returning UPnPError 708: Unsupported or invalid search criteria
[2017/12/01 11:18:52] inotify.c:198: warn: WARNING: Inotify max_user_watches [8192] is low or close to the number of used watches [3] and I do not have permission to increase this limit.  Please do so manually by writing a higher value into /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches.
[2017/12/01 11:19:08] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly
[2017/12/01 11:19:28] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly
[2017/12/01 11:19:48] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly
[2017/12/01 11:20:08] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly
[2017/12/01 11:20:28] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly
[2017/12/01 11:20:48] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly
[2017/12/01 11:21:08] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly
[2017/12/01 11:21:28] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly
[2017/12/01 11:21:48] upnphttp.c:1052: warn: HTTP Connection closed unexpectedly

Comment: Si tienes correctamente configurado todo. Prueba a hacer lo siguiente. Desinstala completamente el minidlna. Haz purge incluido                               `sudo apt-get purge minidlna` y vuelvelo a instalar, cuando lo tengas para el servicio y reconfiguralo (copia antes de hacer el purge si tienes metida muchas cosas)

Comment: Digamos que para dejarlo bien siempre he tenido que hacer eso y claro... Es molesto

Comment: Nada sigue sin funcionar, pego el LOG... Gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas,
Hay veces que miniDLNA no actualiza bien sus bases de datos, te dejo un link con la solucion

https://community.netgear.com/t5/Stora-Legacy/Script-for-to-clear-and-rebuild-MiniDLNA-database/td-p/467947

Esta al final, asi que te pongo los dos comandos aqui

```
sudo minidlna -R
sudo service minidlna restart
```

Con el primero fuerzas la regeneracion del las bases de datos, y con el segundo reinicias el servicio

Atte

Comment: Digamos que siempre da errores por ese tema y estoy haciendo eso siempre... Ya he visto el error, veo que cada vez que hay algo nuevo o antiguo, por tema permisos mi usuario no podia entrar (me podeis poner porfavor el comando chown para que siempre todo lo que haya en un directorio, pueda tener acceso? Gracias) por cierto, no tiene arreglo siempre eso de minidlnad -R??? Yo no hago el restart del service porque no me funcionaria el minidlna.... :S

Comment: Tan solo haciendo sudo minidlnad -R funciona perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Es facil, los permisos en debian si distinguen en tres partes, Dueño, Grupo Dueño, Resto, Dueño es el que crea el archivo, Grupo Dueño es el grupo de quien crea el archivo (salvo que se cambia), Resto es los demas, como supongo que el usuario de MiniDLNA no esta en tu grupo (y obviamente no eres tu), lo que te propongo es que pongas los permisos para la parte Resto en lectura y ejecucion, el comando, lo que hace es, al grupo Resto(o), le asigna los valores Read(r) y Execute(x), a la ruta que le indiques "Tu_ruta". Ademas, como puede ser que tengas carpetas por debajo que quieres que tengan los mismos permisos, pones Recursividad(-R).
Lo he puesto asi para afectar solo a la parte Others, pero podrias ver que permisos tiene la carpeta para la parte dueño y grupo, y hacer chmod xx5 -R "Tu_ruta".

Te dejo un link con informacion 
[chmod](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Comment: Muy interesante... muchas gracias por tus conocimientos y tu tiempo. Doy por valida tu respuesta sobre permisos ya que era el problema (estoy provocando fallo a ver, pero no veo de momento) un saludo colega

Answer (score 0):

A mi me dio muchos problemas al principio en un Debian 8.1, pero la verdad que después de actualizar el servicio (apt-get update && apt-get upgrade), en alguna actualización el problema desaparecía.
Para el tema de permisos, habría que ver en que grupo estas tu y en que grupo esta la ejecución del minidlna, una opción es añadir el usuario de MiniDLNA a tu grupo, o hacer un chmod en tu carpeta para permitir la lectura y ejecución por parte de MiniDLNA. si no me equivoco, deberia ser algo asi

```
sudo chmod o=rx -R "Tu_ruta"
```

Con eso, deberias dar permisos de lectura y ejecucion al others (que supongo es el caso) sobre la ruta indicada y todos sus subdirectorios
Atte

Comment: Disculpa puedes explicar "o=rx" porfavor? Muchas gracias